# docker-compose Nextcloud Instance behind reverse proxy Bad gateway 502

Tags: docker, networking, reverse-proxy, nextcloud

I want to switch from using the `docker run`-command to a `docker-compose` file with my nextcloud instance that runs behind a reverse proxy (jwilder/nginx-proxy).

This is the run command I used to use:

`sudo docker run -d -p 8080:80 --expose 80 --expose 443 -e VIRTUAL_HOST=nextcloud.example.com -v nextcloud:/var/www/html --restart=always --name=nextcloud nextcloud:24.0.8`

I installed the mariaDB later in the container so that I didn't have to struggle with networking. Also I use the Port 8080 only in my internal network for fast up- and downloading.

This worked quite well, but now I want to create a similar environment with `docker-compose`:

```
version: '3.8'

volumes:
  nextcloud:
  db:

services:
  db:
    image: mariadb:10.5
    restart: always
    command: --transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED --binlog-format=ROW
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-super-strong-password
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=my-other-super-strong-password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_USER=nextcloud

  app:
    image: nextcloud:24.0.8
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    expose:
      - 80
      - 443
    links:
      - db
    volumes:
      - nextcloud:/var/www/html
    environment:
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=my-other-super-strong-password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_USER=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_HOST=db
      - PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT=1G
      - PHP_UPLOAD_LIMIT=128M
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=nextcloud.example.com
```

The containers are starting successfully and I can use nextcloud in my internal network. But I cannot reach them from my domain. Instead I get a `502 Bad request`. The VIRTUAL_HOST redirection seems to work since I'd get a `503 Service Temporarily Unavailable` instead.
I think exposing the ports 80 and 443 doesn't work.

I've tried to add a proxy network:

```
networks:
  proxy:
    driver: bridge
    external: true
```

and added

```
networks:
      - default
```

to the db service and

```
networks:
      - default
      - proxy
```

to the app service.

That didn't fixed the problem. Does any of you have an idea what I can try next?

I've tried different ways to expose the ports and tried to create different networks

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind found the problem.

Instead of simply creating an network named `proxy`, I had to create a new jwilder reverse-proxy service via docker compose with a name, as an example `myreverseproxy`. In each service I want to make public I needed to name this proxy as:

```
networks:
  - default
  - myreverseproxy
```

Also I had to use the name in the networks service area:

```
networks:
  myreverseproxy:
    external: true
```